# MySQL Hex to Dec conversion (issue with large numbers)

Tags: mysql

I have an input column in my MySQL database that ends with the 64-character long hexadecimal strings.

Example:
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000019d971e4fe8401e74000000

I am using the following **SUBSTRING(input, 139, 64)** to get it out and then trim leading zeros from the string using **TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM** and finally CONV(x, 16,10) to convert it from HEX to Decimal value.

The final select statement looks like this:

```
SELECT CONV(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM SUBSTRING(input, 139, 64)), 16, 10) AS burning
FROM db
```

Everything is fine when the string looks like this:
80
It's converted to Decimal value:
128

Or when it looks like this:
1b8
to a correct decimal value of: 440

However, when the string looks like this:
**19d971e4fe8401e74000000**
CONV converts it into 18446744073709551615, which is a wrong hex to dec conversion.
The correct return should be: **500000000000000000000000000**

What am I doing wrong? Is there some limit in CONV that breaks the function?

Comment: `18,446,744,073,709,551,615 = pow(2, 64) - 1`. It seems the result of `conv` is capped at maximum uint64 value.

Comment: any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv):

"***CONV() works with 64-bit precision***"

Thats means that a value which exceeds 64-bit will be truncated:

```
select (conv("19d971e4fe8401e74000000",16,10))\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
(conv("19d971e4fe8401e74000000",16,10)): 18446744073709551615
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,001 sec)

show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '19d971e4fe8401e74000000'
1 row in set (0,001 sec)

select hex(18446744073709551615)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
hex(18446744073709551615): FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
1 row in set (0,001 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @val = '19d971e4fe8401e74000000';
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT CONV(RIGHT(@val, 8), 16, 10) part,
         LEFT(@val, GREATEST(LENGTH(@val) - 8, 0)) rest,
         CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(40,0)) multiplier
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONV(RIGHT(rest, 8), 16, 10),
         LEFT(rest, GREATEST(LENGTH(rest) - 8, 0)),
         CAST(multiplier AS DECIMAL(40,0)) * CAST(POW(2, 32) AS DECIMAL(40,0))
  FROM cte
  WHERE rest <> ''
)
SELECT SUM(CAST(CAST(part AS DECIMAL(40,0)) * CAST(multiplier AS DECIMAL(40,0)) AS DECIMAL(40,0))) result
FROM cte
```

| result |
| --- |
| 500000000000000000000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iIT7XwkW)

Of course, some CASTs may be excess. And `DECIMAL(40,0)` may be expanded.. slightly.

Comment: Note this does not allow arbitrary length arithmetic, because in MySQL, DECIMAL has a maximum precision of 65. I don't know of any solution for arbitrary length arithmetic in MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin This is because I have said that the DECIMAL length can be increased only slightly. In practice the precision of 65 can be achieved only while storing/retrieving, none calculations provides such precision.

Comment: This seems to work, but how do I incorporate it into my select statement?
How do I change this to work with your code:
SELECT input AS burning FROM db